# Access value of array inside another array

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array an it is as follows as a result of dd().

```
dd($request->user['test'])
```

-result of dd()

```
  array:4 [
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "Test1"
      "created_at" => "2016-02-21 23:05:43"
      "updated_at" => "2016-02-21 23:05:43"
    ]
```

how can I access 'name' indide above array.

Comment: Try this `dd($request->user['test']['name'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
dd($request->user['test']['name']);
```